# NullPointerException in my active code

Tags: java, oracle, nullpointerexception, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a problem with my code. I am using Oracle JDeveloper 12c and I can't deal with my code. I have a method called deactivate:

```
   public void deactivate() {
    DeesconfViewImpl deak = getDeesconfView();
    RowSetIterator rowSetIterator = deak.createRowSetIterator("New");
    if (rowSetIterator != null) {
        rowSetIterator.reset();
        while (rowSetIterator.hasNext()) {
          Row currentRow = rowSetIterator.next();
            currentRow.setAttribute("Active", 0);
        }
        rowSetIterator.closeRowSetIterator();
    }
}
```

which has a problem in line:
DeesconfViewImpl deak = getDeesconfView();

He doesn't see that getDeesconfView, JDeveloper gives me a hint to insert a method

```
private DeesconfViewImpl getDeesconfView() {
    return null;
}
```

And code compiles succesfully, but I have nullPointerException in my method, which is supposed to set all rows to inactive, and this one I selected to active:

```
public void activeYear() {
        deactivate(); 

    this.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("Active", 1);
}
```

I am sure that the problem is 
DeesconfViewImpl deak = getDeesconfView();
but I have no idea what could go in this code. If I remove this line, I have an error with:

```
public class DeesconfViewImpl extends ViewObjectImpl implements DeesconfView {
        private static DeesconfView getDeesconfView;
}
```

That he doesn't see getDeesconfView. Seems like he just doesn't use it.

Yes I debugged it and I found out already which line causes this error.

Comment: `NPE` can be easily found out once you **Debug** . so have you try that first ?

Comment: Which line is causing the NPE ?

Comment: There is **exactly** one reason for an NPE. The stack trace tells you *exactly* which line of your code is the problem. You need to debug your code and figure out why you have a `null` reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: The line that caused nullPointerException is

Answer (score 0):

The first line

```
DeesconfViewImpl deak = getDeesconfView();
```

will call the function `getDeesconfView()` which will return a `null` value. Thus the Second line

```
 RowSetIterator rowSetIterator = deak.createRowSetIterator("New");
```

will make a

```
RowSetIterator rowSetIterator = null.createRowSetIterator("New");
```

which will make the `NullPointerException` .

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDeesconfView()` method will always returns `null`.That's why you are getting NPE.